# Create dependencies.gradle in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, gradle-dependencies

How can I create `dependencies.gradle` in android studio like bellow:

[image]

And:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a file called `dependencies.gradle` and add the `dependencies {}` there ...then in a module's `build.gradle`, you can reference them with `apply from: "dependencies.gradle"`. this screenshot are just library version numbers for the dependencies, which **may** be defined and then can be referenced in a `dependencies.gradle`; for example`"${versions.okhttp}"`.

And I don't really understand the question, because the project you've posted the screenshot from appears to be Android Studio, shows "How can I create `dependencies.gradle` in android studio like below".

Comment: @ Martin Zeitler. Thank's a lot for your help.